# Error Max values per tag limit exceeded InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I am facing

> max values per tag limit exceeded

issue when trying to write 200k points to Influx DB (version 1.2.4) through Java by specifying the batch size and poll interval. I have also set `max-values-per-tag = 0` in `/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf` but still facing the following issue.

```
SEVERE: Batch could not be sent. Data will be lost
org.influxdb.InfluxDBException: {"error":"partial write: max-values-per-tag limit exceeded (100453/100000): measurement=\"samplemeasurement\" tag=\"sampletag\" value=\"samplevalue99195\" dropped=806"}
    at org.influxdb.impl.InfluxDBImpl.execute(InfluxDBImpl.java:511)
    at org.influxdb.impl.InfluxDBImpl.write(InfluxDBImpl.java:312)
    at org.influxdb.impl.BatchProcessor.write(BatchProcessor.java:248)
    at org.influxdb.impl.BatchProcessor$2.run(BatchProcessor.java:278)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this problem occurred today.The reason is simple,you cannot define too many different tag value.

the following is quoted from official document:

*The maximum number of tag values allowed per tag key. The default setting is 100000. Change the setting to 0 to allow an unlimited number of tag values per tag key.*

cuz the this number connected with *series-cardinality*.
too high series-cardinality may kill influxdb process and cause other damage such as OOM.

at last sorry for poor English.Hope it will help you

Comment: so you mean we should not set a very high value for this?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error. I changed the **max-values-per-tag = 0**,still I got the same error.Then I changed **max-series-per-database = 0**, still it didn't work.

But eventually I found out that if you **decrease the number of measurements per database and also the number of rows  in each measurement** then this error doesn't occur.

As soon as my number of measurements per database exceeded 40-50 I started getting this error. So to reduce the number of measurements I used **Tags**  and also made sure that my **database gets refreshed**(deleting previous values) every 18 hours(roughly when it has 1 lakh rows in it).

I'm not an expert in this thing But it worked for me. Hope it does for you too.